# In Java is it possible to add a operation into a switch? or whats the best way to code this

Tags: java

the code asks me to mention the following: name, id, status, hour, following by pay due:
the status follows a charting 
FT - 345 per hour
PT - 200 per hour

I was how will it be possible to code something like this?

```java
String Name;
String badge number;
int hour;

System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
Name = keyboard.next( );

System.out.print("Enter your badgenumber:  ");
badgenumber = keyboard.next( );

System.out.print("How many hour are you working: ");
hour = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("Choose a Status: FT, PT,");
String Status = keyboard.next();

switch (Status) {
    case "FT":
        System.out.println("Due :  hour * 345 ) ;
        break;
    case "PT":
        System.out.println("Due : hour * 200);
}
```

Help: not sure if any of this makes sense but I want that when you enter the status it outputs the hour * pay per hour . [if it's not possible with switch please tell me which is a better way to go about the problem]

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking.

Comment: @DaveNewton basically I am stuck on finding a way have in the system the status and how much their prices are per hour. (ex if you are PT you pay 200 per hour) so if I say my status if PT, I want the program to be able to say "pay due: 200 * my hours) and gives me a total. or if not possible just a better to get my total due

Comment: Synthetic error, it should be  System.out.println("Due :  " + (hour * 345) ) ;

Answer (score 1):

Though not very practical, I will throw an alternative way with HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> wageMultiplier = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

wageMultiplier.put("FT", 345);
wageMultiplier.put("PT", 200);

int hours = 4;

int wage = hours * wageMultiplier.get("FT");
```

Answer (score -1):

just write:

```
switch (Status) {
case "FT":
    System.out.println("Due :" + hour * 345 ) ;
    break;
case "PT":
    System.out.println("Due :" + hour * 200);}
```

and btw it's good to always check your inputs using if's
for example:

```
if(Status != "PT" && Status != "FT")
    {
System.out.println("you have entered an invalid input."); 
exit(1);
}
```

Comment: While it's good to validate data, using 'if's aren't always the best. What if you add a 'default' case to your switch statement, then it would handle, 'FT', 'PT', and anything else.